# Flipkart.com product scraping using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

The following Python module checks if the specified item is present on flipkart.com:

```
import sys
import bs4
import re
import urllib2

def findItem(itemName):
    itemName.replace(" ", "+")      
    link = 'http://www.flipkart.com/search/a/all?query= {0}&vertical=all&dd=0&autosuggest[as]=off&autosuggest[as-submittype]=entered&autosuggest[as-grouprank]=0&autosuggest[as-overallrank]=0&autosuggest[orig-query]=&autosuggest[as-shown]=off&Search=%C2%A0&otracker=start&_r=YSWdYULYzr4VBYklfpZRbw--&_l=pMHn9vNCOBi05LKC_PwHFQ--&ref=a2c6fadc-2e24-4412-be6a-ce02c9707310&selmitem=All+Categories'.format(itemName)
    r = urllib2.Request(link, headers={"User-Agent": "Python-urlli~"})
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(r)
    except:
        print "Internet connection error"
        return     
    thePage = response.read()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(thePage)
    firstBlockSoup = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'size1of4 fk-medium-atom unit'})
    if not firstBlockSoup:
        print "Item Not Found"
        return
    else:
        print "Item found"
        return
```

The above module works for some, but not all the products on flipkart.com

For example, it works for:

```
findItem("galaxy s advance")
```

but not for:

```
findItem("Giordano Analog Watch")
```

The reason for this will be apparent if you check the source code, on flipkart.com, of the pages for the above two products (better by using "Inspect element") and relate it to the code.

Can anybody please suggest a fool-proof method for accomplishing the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you just split it into two checks:

```
import urllib2

import bs4


def findItem(itemName):
    itemName.replace(" ", "+")
    link = 'http://www.flipkart.com/search/a/all?query= {0}&vertical=all&dd=0&autosuggest[as]=off&autosuggest[as-submittype]=entered&autosuggest[as-grouprank]=0&autosuggest[as-overallrank]=0&autosuggest[orig-query]=&autosuggest[as-shown]=off&Search=%C2%A0&otracker=start&_r=YSWdYULYzr4VBYklfpZRbw--&_l=pMHn9vNCOBi05LKC_PwHFQ--&ref=a2c6fadc-2e24-4412-be6a-ce02c9707310&selmitem=All+Categories'.format(
        itemName)
    r = urllib2.Request(link, headers={"User-Agent": "Python-urlli~"})
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(r)
    except:
        print "Internet connection error"
        return
    thePage = response.read()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(thePage)

    firstBlockSoup = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'product-unit'})
    if not firstBlockSoup:
        firstBlockSoup = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'size1of4 fk-medium-atom unit'})
        if not firstBlockSoup:
            print "Item Not Found"
            return

    print "Item found"
    return


findItem("galaxy s advance")
findItem("Giordano Analog Watch")
findItem("nosuchitemfound")
```

Prints:

```
Item found
Item found
Item Not Found
```

Another way is to check if "No results page" exists. For example, just check for `"0 results found" in soup.text`.

Comment: Thanks. But it looks like different checks have to be performed for different Categories. So to check for "No Results Found" as suggested by you is a better alternative.

Comment: On a related note, please try to answer this question ASAP.

http://stackoverflow.com/q/16379286/2329308