# Flipkart.com product 'price' and product 'title' extraction using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written the following Python code to extract the PRICE of the **item specified** from flipkart.com

```
import urllib2
import bs4
import re

item="Wilco Classic Library: Autobiography Of a Yogi (Hardcover)"
item.replace(" ", "+")
link = 'http://www.flipkart.com/search/a/all?query={0}&vertical=all&dd=0&autosuggest[as]=off&autosuggest[as-submittype]=entered&autosuggest[as-grouprank]=0&autosuggest[as-overallrank]=0&autosuggest[orig-query]=&autosuggest[as-shown]=off&Search=%C2%A0&otracker=start&_r=YSWdYULYzr4VBYklfpZRbw--&_l=pMHn9vNCOBi05LKC_PwHFQ--&ref=a2c6fadc-2e24-4412-be6a-ce02c9707310&selmitem=All+Categories'.format(item)
r = urllib2.Request(link, headers={"User-Agent": "Python-urlli~"})
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(r)
except:
    print "Internet connection error"  
thePage = response.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(thePage)
firstBlockSoup = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'fk-srch-item'})
priceSoup=firstBlockSoup.find('b',attrs={'class':'fksd-bodytext price final-price'})
price=priceSoup.contents[0]
print price

titleSoup=firstBlockSoup.find('a',attrs={'class':'fk-srch-title-text fksd-bodytext'})
title=titleSoup.findAll('b')
print title
```

The above code when executed prints the PRICE without issues.

```
Rs. 138
```

But the title is obtained as follows:

```
[<b>Wilco</b>, <b>Classic</b>, <b>Library</b>, <b>Autobiography</b>, <b>Of</b>, <b>a</b>, <b>Yogi</b>, <b>Hardcover</b>]
```

The reason will be apparent if you have a look at the source code of the [product page](http://www.flipkart.com/search-books?query=Wilco%20Classic%20Library:Autobiography%20Of%20a%20Yogi%20%28Hardcover%29&from=all&searchGroup=all&autosuggest%5Bas%5D=off&autosuggest%5Bas-submittype%5D=entered&autosuggest%5Bas-grouprank%5D=0&autosuggest%5Bas-overallrank%5D=0&autosuggest%5Borig-query%5D=&autosuggest%5Bas-shown%5D=off&selmitem=All%20Categories&otracker=start&vertical=all&_l=WE_JphiGfT8Bh6aXp1vT2w--&_r=_MFMNA8pxFY3ZpKGrqRTOA--&ref=b015ecfa-833a-4e1b-b50e-11b9515d2498) (use 'Inspect element')

Now, How do I extract the TITLE in a proper format so as to print:

```
Wilco Classic Library: Autobiography Of a Yogi (Hardcover)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `text` method on `titleSoup`

```
>>> titleSoup=firstBlockSoup.find('a',attrs={'class':'fk-srch-title-text fksd-bodytext'})
>>> titleSoup.text
u'Wilco Classic Library: Autobiography Of a Yogi (Hardcover)'
```

This will also work:

```
invalid_tags = ['b']
titleSoup=firstBlockSoup.find('a',attrs={'class':'fk-srch-title-text fksd-bodytext'})

for tag in invalid_tags: 
    for match in titleSoup.findAll(tag):
       match.replaceWithChildren()
print "".join(titleSoup.contents)
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll be easier to get the title from the `firstBlockSoup` tag:

```
>>> firstBlockSoup.attrs['data-item-name']
'Wilco Classic Library: Autobiography Of a Yogi (Hardcover)'
```

Comment: I loaded the same URL you did, with your code. Your `titleSoup` element returned `None` for me.

Comment: This is weird. After looking at your comment, I executed the same code 10 times. Twice out of 10 times the _titleSoup_ element returned __None__.     
I cannot think of any possible explanation for this behavior. Let me know if you figure it out. Thank you.